# adding <br/> to the text-box when user press enter key in jquery

Tags: jquery, newline, onkeyup

I want to add the `<br/>` (newline) to text box  when user clicks on the enter button.

How can I achieve it in jquery `onkeyup` event. Can one show me the example or any good website implementing it.

Thank you

Comment: Might this be something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157739/jquery-how-can-i-add-line-break-to-form-input/2157769#2157769 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copied from here [Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea) See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xeubq/)**.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function ()
    {
        $('#txt').keyup(function (e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13){
                var curr = getCaret(this);
                var val = $(this).val();
                var end = val.length;

                $(this).val( val.substr(0, curr) + '<br>' + val.substr(curr, end));
            }

        })
    });

    function getCaret(el) { 
        if (el.selectionStart) { 
            return el.selectionStart; 
        }
        else if (document.selection) { 
            el.focus(); 

            var r = document.selection.createRange(); 
            if (r == null) { 
                return 0; 
            } 

            var re = el.createTextRange(), 
            rc = re.duplicate(); 
            re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark()); 
            rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re); 

            return rc.text.length; 
        }  
        return 0; 
    }

</script>
<div id="content">
    <textarea id="txt" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

Well, i guess all text-editors (WYSIWYG) do it all the time.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i dont want to display <br />when user press enter how can i add it into the hidden field .i am new to the jquery can u help me

Comment: @sarath, well, i think these text editors use `hidden` element to store the values. These guys are pretty smart.

Comment: i dont want to use any text editors now since i am using this text box only in 2 places and i dont have time to explore it, so can i make changes here only so that i can finish it early

Comment: @sarath well, you can store this value in a hidden element - there's no other way (and also put some (single) character) so that backspace allows deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of :

```
$('#some-field').keyup(function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == '13') {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).append("<br />\n");
  }
});
```

Comment: This puts it at the end instead of where the cursor is

Comment: Instead of append use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621931/insert-text-on-the-current-place-of-the-cursor-in-the-browser

Comment: Good point, he should use a caret plugin then : http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/caret