# adding new line character (BR) but BR must be hidden in text box when user press enter in jquery

Tags: jquery, newline, onkeyup

My question is the same as the question stated in [adding <br/> to the text-box when user press enter key in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455104/)

I am getting `br` but I want to hide the `<br>` character when user press enter I dont want to display `<br>` in the text box.

Comment: You might need to do it a bit differently. Maybe replacing \n with <br /> after the user submits the form? I don't think you'll be able to hide the input without some serious hacking.

Answer (score 1):

By textbox, I assume you're talking about a textarea. Then you should be adding a `\n` instead of a BR.

Comment: while the \n might not show up as text in your DB, it should be adding a break in your text. Alternatively you can call `nl2br` and `str_replace()` to switch between `\n` or `<br>`