# How to make text to jump new line in the textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, textarea

I have a problem making a text jump to a new line in the textarea. It will show `</br>` words in the textarea. May I know how to avoid `</br>` words show in the text area and can make the text jump to a new line? Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Below is my sample coding:

```js
$("textarea[name='default_kandungan']").val('Alex</br>Peter</br>John')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <textarea type="text" " id="default_kandungan" name="default_kandungan" value="" title="Default Kandungan"></textarea>
```

Actually, I want the expected results like below the picture:

[image: output 1]

Comment: Try : `.val('Alex\nPeter\nJohn')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157739/jquery-how-can-i-add-line-break-to-form-input this might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `<br>` tag directly, use `\n`

```js
$("textarea[name='default_kandungan']").val('Alex\nPeter\nJohn')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <textarea type="text"  id="default_kandungan" name="default_kandungan" value="" title="Default Kandungan"></textarea>
```